# Молиться - о или за?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "молиться о ком-то" или "молиться за кого-то"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словарях регламентируется употребление глагола *молиться*  с дательным падежом (кому-чему) без предлога, и с винительным с предлогом на (на кого-что) в значении 'обожать, боготворить'. 
Думаю, с глаголом *молиться* в значении 'просить' можно использовать и предложный падеж (о ком-чем), и винительный (за кого). (Д. Э. Розенталь "Управление в русском языке". Москва, 1986 г.)

Answer (score 1):

В принципе оба варианта возможны, с несколько разным смыслом. Надо бы контекст посмотреть.     
Хотя вообще-то обычно молятся **о чем-либо** и **за кого-либо**.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта верны.

Comment: Вот так-то! Через несколько дней заглянула в словарь управления, а там: молить - о чем, за кого, чего; молиться - кому-чему, на кого-что. Получается, правильно: я за тебя молю, я о тебе молю,я о здоровье молю , а Богу молюсь, на тебя молюсь. Или я не права?

Comment: Это Лопатин?
Там даётся управление только при втором значении молиться - "обожать", "боготворить". На основное значение никаких ограничительных рекомендаций нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то в узусе довольно распространено "молиться о ком-то". У Ахматовой, например:

"Эта женщина больна,
Эта женщина одна,
Муж в могиле, сын в тюрьме,
Помолитесь обо мне".

Comment: Как правильно-то? — спрашивают.

Comment: Таисия, пишите подробнее, так, чтобы можно было бы сразу понять именно ответ именно на поставленный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Кратко из Церк. букваря (Проп. и строч. по ориг.). Молитва к (крестителю, ангелу хранителю), ко (святым апостолам и всем святым; пресвятой богородице); молитва (святому, которого носишь имя; честному кресту господню); молитва за (царя; упокой душ усопших)  молитва о здравии и спасении живых; молитва пред (началом дела, учением), по окончании, после ужина.

Что есть молитва? Молитва есть возношение мысли и сердца нашего к богу с прошением от него полезных благ.

Ответ очевиден: всё возможно, жёсткой нормы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Молиться за кого-то означает вместо него (для сравнения: я отработаю смену за тебя), т.е. беру на себя общение с Богом, а ты остаешься в стороне. Молиться о ком-то означает ходатайствовать об этом человеке. "И сказал Господь: Симон! Симон! се, сатана просил,чтобы сеять вас как пшеницу, но Я молился о тебе, чтобы не оскудела вера твоя..." Ев. от Луки 22:31,32.

Comment: Хотелось бы более аргументированного мнения.